# definite integral which have $\sin$ function.

Tags: calculus

Finding $\displaystyle \int^{\pi}_{0}x^2\ln(\sin x)dx$

Solution I try

Assume $\displaystyle I =\int^{\pi}_{0}x^2\ln(\sin x)dx=\int^{\pi}_{0}x^2\ln(2\sin x/2 \cos x/2)dx$

$\displaystyle I=\int^{\pi}_{0}x^2\ln(\sin \frac{x}{2})dx+\int^{\pi}_{0}x^2\ln(\cos \frac{x}{2})dx+\int^{\pi}_{0}x^2\ln(2)dx$

$\displaystyle I=8\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}t^2\ln\sin(t)dt+8\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}t^2\ln\cos(t)dt+2\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\ln(2)dt$

I do not understand how can I solve it.

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2768626/how-to-solve-the-integration/2768646#comment5709757_2768646 for a very nice solution.

Comment: @Claude it is not given in that question.

Comment: The solution is given by $$-\frac{1}{6} \pi  \left(3 \zeta (3)+\pi ^2 \log
   (4)\right)$$

Comment: Look at the first integral which is $\displaystyle \int^{\pi}_{0}x^3\ln(\sin x)dx$ and do the same with $x^2$ instead of $x^3$.

Comment: Thanks Claude. I am searching for elementry solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Begin by 
$$
\displaystyle \int^{v}_{u}x^2\ln(\sin x)dx=\displaystyle \int^{v}_{u}\Big(\frac{x^3}{3}\Big)'\ln(\sin x)dx
$$
and use integration by parts.

Of course, you will have to prove the convergence when $u\to 0$ and $v\to \pi$.

You can also use the Fourier series for $0<x<\pi$
$$
-\log(\sin(x))=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(2kx)}{k}+\log(2)
$$
If needed, look at the very elegant derivation of it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos) by user17762.
And then use, as was indicated, the technique of [Jacky Chong](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2768626/how-to-solve-the-integration)

For your information, computer algebra gives (same as Dr. Sonnhard Graubner)
$$
-1/6\pi^3\log(4) - 1/2\pi\zeta(3)\ .
$$